# Powershell: Sort percent number

Tags: powershell

Got a small problem with sorting percent numbers.
I just wrote a simple script to test:

```
function get-percent{
$obj1 = New-Object PSObject
$percentUsed1="{0:P0}" -f (100/100)      
$obj1 | Add-Member -membertype NoteProperty -Name 'Percent' -Value $percentUsed1

$obj2 = New-Object PSObject
$percentUsed2="{0:P0}" -f (99/100)      
$obj2 | Add-Member -membertype NoteProperty -Name 'Percent' -Value $percentUsed2

$obj3 = New-Object PSObject
$percentUsed3="{0:P0}" -f (8/100)      
$obj3 | Add-Member -membertype NoteProperty -Name 'Percent' -Value $percentUsed3

$obj4 = New-Object PSObject
$percentUsed4="{0:P0}" -f (70/100)      
$obj4 | Add-Member -membertype NoteProperty -Name 'Percent' -Value $percentUsed4


write $obj1
write $obj2
write $obj3
write $obj4

}


get-percent | sort-object 'Percent' -descending |ft
```

Here is what i get:

### Percent

99%
8%
70%
100 %

Normally, I should have: 100 % , 99%, 70%...
Any ideas guys ?
Thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
get-percent | sort-object  { [INT]($_.percent -replace '%')  } -descending
```

In this way `sort-object` can sort by `[INT]` and not by `[String]` as  before.

Comment: It works ! What was the problem ? I can't vote up ( vote up requires 15 reputation...)

Comment: @MatStack No problem. IIRC I think you can accept it as the answer clicking on the V sign.